# Converting integer to binary/decimal in MIPS assembly?

Tags: assembly, binary, integer, mips

I have a program, in MIPS, which passes either the value '2' or '10' in a register to a function which is supposed to then print some integer in binary or decimal, depending on whether 2 or 10 was passed into the function. I'm trying to think up of clever ways to implement this but can't think of any so I've come to ask for help. Can anyone help me out?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just check to see if the 4th bit is 1 or 0.  You could do this with a bitshift to or `OR` operator against a `0x00001000` mask.

Comment: Could you explain how that helps? A 1 as the 4th bit is 8, yes?

Comment: This because it is already known ahead of time that the value will be either 2 or 10.  If the 4th bit is set, then the value is at least 8.  This means that the value is not 2.  Since the value is not 2, the value has to be the only other possible value, which is 10.